# SQL UPDATE many-to-many

Tags: sql

У меня есть две таблицы - `task(id, name)` и `method(id, max_run)`, которые связаны типом many-to-many через таблицу `taskmethod(id, task_id, method_id)`.

Мне необходимо задать значение поля для method.max_run записи, которая соответствует нужному имени task.name

Например, есть связанные записи:

```
task(001, 'MAIN_TASK')
taskmethod(1, 001, 005)
method(005, 10)
```

Я представляю себе запрос приблизительно таким:

```
UPDATE method
SET max_run = 5
(для записи, для которой task.name = 'MAIN_TASK')
```

Это предположения, поскольку в SQL я разбираюсь слабо.
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `where task_id in(select id from task where name='MAIN_TASK')`. А вообще это базовый уровень знаний SQL, получается за 1 день а потом используется всю жизнь, имеет смысл изучить его

Comment: Знаний, изученных за один день, мне, как видите, не хватило :) Не могли бы Вы оформить свой комментарий в отдельный ответ с полным запросом, чтобы я мог принять его как правильный?

Comment: Поскольку связь много-ко-много, будут обновлены **все** записи таблицы `method`, связанные с этой записью таблицы `task` через таблицу `taskmethod`. Вам точно нужно именно это?

Comment: И укажите DBMS - некоторые допускают многотабличное обновление, некоторые нет.

Comment: кстати, Mike, Ваш пример не работает. Видимо, одного дня изучения SQL всё-таки не достаточно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE method
SET max_run = 5
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT
        a.method_id
    FROM taskmethod a
    JOIN task b ON a.task_id = b.id
    WHERE b.name like 'MAIN_TASK')
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно то, что нужно.